# Username is number?

Tags: apache2, users

I cannot work this out. If I'm logged in as root (using chroot - possibly) then all my actions (e.g. mkdir) are assigned to the user `root`.

For my websites I need to associate files and directories and such to a specific user which appears to be linked to the virtual host account for the hosting account. (Its a dedicated hosting server - we log into the control panel and click "create account". This creates a new dir in `/home` with a `www/public_html` dir in it). For instance here is a screenshot of the `www` folder for one account:

[image]

I don't understand what its all about. The user appears to be `2045` however this is a number. Typing `id 2045` into the command line results in `id: 2045: No such user` so does `id "2045"`.

You can `chown 2045:sites` though, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on. Is `2045` a user? Or something else I don't know about?

What I really want to do is be able to switch user (su) to 2045 and run the commands so that I don't have to `chown` every time I do something (I work with SVN a lot).

Any insight would be very helpful. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `ls -l` shows a number instead of a group/user name, that is a UID/GID (User ID/Group ID). In your case, `2045` is a GID. You can get the user/group names (along with other information) using the following commands:

```
getent passwd UID
getent group GID
```

Example:

```
$ getent passwd 1000
andrea:x:1000:1000:Andrea Corbellini,,,:/home/andrea:/bin/bash
$ getent group 1000
andrea:x:1000:
```

Comment: Ah I see, thats cool. So these files and directories are owned by two groups? 2045 and sites? How can I run commands as the group 2045?

Comment: No, it's owned by group 2045 and user sites. To run a command as a different group, you can use `sudo -g group-name`. In this case, as you don't have the group name but its ID, you should use `sudo -g "#2045"` (remember the quotes!). Note that you can specify both `-g` and `-u` at the same time.